Let a real symmetric matrix $M=Q \Lambda Q^T$. Under what conditions on $Q$ and $\Lambda$ is $M$ diagonal?
Let $M$ be a real symmetric matrix that has an eigendecomposition $M=Q \Lambda Q^T$, where $Q$ is an orthogonal matrix. Under what conditions on $Q$ and $\Lambda$ is $M$ diagonal?
Thoughts: $M$ and $\Lambda$ are similar, so they share eigenvalues. Therefore if $M$ is diagonal it is a permutation of $\Lambda$. $Q$ being a permutation matrix is a sufficient condition, but not necessary. Consider $\Lambda = \operatorname{diag}(1, 1, 2)$ and
$$
Q =
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{-\sqrt{3}}{2} & 0 \\ 
\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
a rotation that only effects the two axes with equal eigenvalues. Then $Q \Lambda Q^T$ is diagonal and in fact equal to $\Lambda$.

You already have eigendecomposition of $M$,so matrices $Q$ and $\Lambda$ already satisfy your required conditions.

@SandeepTiwari, the question is what matrices $Q$ and $\Lambda$ will result in a diagonal $M$. Clearly not all will as the decomposition $Q \Lambda Q^T$ exists for any real symmetric $M$.

"Eigendecomposition of a matrix"
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#:~:text=Eigendecomposition%20of%20a-,matrix,-edit

All real symmetric matrices are orthogonally diagonalizable.

@SandeepTiwari, the question isn't whether $M$ is diagonalizable (the diagonalization is provided). The question is whether $M$ is diagonal.
